# Right derivative of a continuous nondecreasing map

Tags: calculus

If $[a,b)$ ($a<b$) is an interval in $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is a continuous non-decreasing real-valued map on $[a,b)$, then $f$ has a right-derivative at any point $x\in[a,b)$, correct? (I have not been able to find a proof.)

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sqrt x$ on $[0,1)$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I will reformulate. Take the open interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: Do you know the cantor function?

Comment: I know it is continuous and increasing and has a derivative almost everywhere. Am I right? But does it have a right derivative everywhere?

Comment: sorry. Please forget the cantor function. That makes thing unnecessarily complicated. Consider $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ on any open interval containing $0$.

Comment: thanks. if one allows the right derivative to take on values in the extended real line, then the claim might hold true...

Comment: I know no useful instance in which one consider $\pm \infty$ as a valid derivative. Notice there is result that a continuous and monotonous function is almost everywhere differentiable.

Comment: the result says that monotonic functions (not necessarily continuous) are almost everywhere differentiable.